# client-side debugging vs server-side debugging in IIS

Tags: iis

What is the difference between these two?
We have a website application hosted in IIS and in side web.config it has:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
```

So the default i assume is debug = false.. so if there are any errors it doesn't print out what the error is on the browser... 
But there was an error with the connection string and the error was printing out on the browser.. so i looked a bit deeper and it turns out that `AppAllowClientDebug` is set to True.
`AppAllowDebugging` is set to false however.

So it seems that some errors are hidden and some are displayed on the browser?

Can someone please explain what is causing this behavior?

Comment: 1) Client side debugging means JavaScript debugging in most cases, so you didn't touch that here. 2) the IIS settings you talked about are for classic ASP, which do not apply to ASP.NET. 3) The debug flag in ASP.NET configuration asks the runtime to compile your web app in debug mode (many runtime differences from release mode). 4) To prevent server side error message from showing in browsers, you should change custom errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85)

Comment: so if i have debug = "false" set and I have an error in my aspx.cs page like inta instead of int or in my aspx page i have a control and i mispelled runat="servera" instead of runat="server", it shouldn't show the error on the browser right? but it does show that.

Comment: What errors you see depend on how severe it bloats the ASP.NET runtime. So when you see IIS error page, yellow page of death, or ASP.NET error pages, the severity differs and they come from different places in the request processing pipeline. It goes beyond a single question, and usually requires you to read an in-depth book on this topic.